# Is there a special term for Sith apprentices?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, sith

Jedi apprentices are referred to as "*padawans*" but **is there an equivalent term for the Sith?**

Darth Vader, the only Sith whose initiation we see, appears to be immediately granted the title of "Darth" which doesn't seem to fit, as the Sith seem to carry that title with them, rather than outgrowing it.

Legends sources are acceptable, as the new canon doesn't seem to answer this.

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith_apprentice/Legends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simply put, no.**

Using the Bane trilogy as a source: There is no title granted to apprentices pre-Darth title.  They are given a name and when the master believes the apprentice is ready they are then given the title of Darth.  Even after they are given the Darth title, they are still called apprentice.